# React useState with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this code

```js
interface AccountData {
  country: number |null;
}
const [accountData, setAccountData] = useState<AccountData>({ country:null });
```

Until we assign a value to a country it can be an undefined, null, or empty string.

Then I set the country value like this

```js
const handleChange = (e: number) => {
  if(!isNaN(e)) {
    setAccountData({ country: e });
  }
};
```

And then I try to pass the value of the country to a function that requires the parameter as a number, I got this error

```html
<Button
  small
  onClick={() => { handleSubmit(accountData.country); }}
>
  save
</Button>
```

> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Which make sense typescript assumes this can be `null` sometimes. So I check if this is a number before I pass to the function like this

```js
onClick={() => {
  if(!isNaN(accountData.country)) {
    handleSubmit(accountData.country);
  }
}}
```

But the error is still there. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can't see any `setAccountData` calls, where is the error actually occurring? The line where you call `handleSubmit`? If so, what is that function expecting as an argument? I think relevant code is missing

Comment: Use `typeof` and check if it's a number before calling `handleSubmit`

Comment: Can you please add definition for handleSubmit?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your `handleSubmit` function, I'm guessing it's annotated with `number`. There is a chance country can be `null` when this is submitted. Therefore TypeScript isn't happy with this.

Something like this might help:

```
const handleSubmit = (input: number | null) => {
  // stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `as` keyword to specify type `number` for `country`.

```
<Button
 small
 onClick={() => {
 handleSubmit(accountData.country as number);
}}>save</Button>
```

Refer: [Type Narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)

Answer (score -1):

If `Counrt` your value `undefined`, `null`, or `empty` string so can define also `any`. Which can accept `undefined`, `null`, or `empty`.

Learn more about [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

```
interface AccountData {
    country: number | null | any;
}

const [accountData, setAccountData] = useState<AccountData>({ country:null });

const handleSubmit = (input: number | null | any) => {
   // do some stuff here
}
```

Comment: Using `any` is like cutting the drawstring to your parachute. There are very few cases it should be used. Using it here, you may as well not have `number` or `null` before it.